# Store text without it's property of being a string in python

Tags: python, string

I know it's a weird question but in the rare case it's possible:
I was looking for a way of storing a text but without it's str property so I can call it in a print and that python can execute it.
I have this text for example:

```
"out('text')"
```

and i want to manipulate it as a string and execute it with python with the interpreter I'm making.

Comment: Where do you want to store it?

Comment: "but without it's str property so I can call it in a print and that python can execute it" I can't understand what this is supposed to mean. What kind of manipulations do you want to do? *What should happen* as a result? And more importantly, **why** do you want to do this? What practical *problem will you solve* this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly how to do what you are asking for. but you can use eval() function in python to compile and run the code in your strings.

```
def printt(a):
    print(a)
    
def add(a,b):
    print(a+b)
    
call = 'printt("hello")'
addnum = 'add(2,5)'

eval(call)
#hello

eval(addnum)
#7
```